# UIViewController Interactive Transition error when cancelled

Tags: ios, swift, interactive, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a **custom transition** between one `UIViewController (VC1)` and a modal `UIViewController (VC2)`. I do it interactively to hide `VC2` with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

When the pan gesture finishes and the translation in the y axis is equal or more than 100pt, I finish the transition with `finishInteractiveTransition()`. Otherwise I cancel transition with `cancelInteractiveTransition()`.

**VC1**

[image]

**VC2**

[image]

**Transition between VC1 and VC2**

[image]

When the transition is cancelled because the pan gesture translation is less than 100pt, the expected behaviour is to revert custom the transition animation and show `VC2` again but instead of this, `VC1` is shown.

You can download the project from my [Github](https://github.com/adriacarro/DYGallery).